# Load Css classes as string in React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface

I have an object in which CSS file code is coming like a string. Like

```
{    
    css: ".button { color: green } .button:after { color: red }"
}
```

How can I load CSS as a string in my React Component?

Comment: If you are able to read that string just parse it, split it by '.' and also by '{' and '}'

Comment: you can append css together and put them inside a `<style>` tag to make them accessible; then add appropriate classes to elements you need

Comment: @SulemanAhmad eval() is for javascript code, not css

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A how can I put a string inside a style? can you please share a snippet of code?

Comment: @ZuhairNaqi, You can do something like this
`let c = { css: ".submit { color: green } .cancel { color: red }" };
let stl = document.createElement("style");
stl.innerText = c.css;
document.body.append(stl);`

Comment: There are libraries that can help you here with React, like [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of putting css into style tag to be used later

> Appending to documnet.head can pollute global css scope; so if that is problematic you can append style to the element you are rendering, therefore the style will be unmounted after component unmounted

```js
function mountStyles ( stylesStr ) {
  const styleTag = document.createElement('style');
  styleTag.textContent = stylesStr;
  document.head.appendChild(styleTag);
}

const someCSS = ".button { color: green } .button:after { color: red } ";

test.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  mountStyles(someCSS);
})
```

```html
<span class='button'> imagniray button </span>
<button id='test' > Click me </button>
```